# Datatable populating from webrequest extemly slow

Tags: json, vb.net, datagridview, datatable, httprequest

I've been diging around a situation that is extremly slow while populating a datatable in **VB.net 2013**.

I have a remote MySQL server with several tables.

As an example let's imagine a table named Student that contains 2 fields. One for StudenID and another for the student name.

The next table is for Courses and as the first it contains 2 fields. One for CourseID and other for Course Name.

Now we also have a third table with several fields and amongst them we have StudentID and CourseID.

So I do a httpRequest with a SQL statement to a service that returns a Json String from the third table with a lot of fields.

I can read and decode the Jsonstring and that is quick, but as I want to display student and course name, I need to do 2 more httpRequests per row to contact the server and using the StudentID fetch his/her name and then fetch the course Name using CourseID, decoding more Json Strings.

I have everything working and a datagrid displays the values as expected, however it is extremely slow taking around 1 second per row. As sometimes we get 300 or more results this becomes impracticable.

I'm pretty sure I'm not using the correct approach. And if someone could help me I would be greatful, as I'm new to VB.net.

My Code is like this

I have a module where I have some http related utils function that I all when needed.

```
 Function HttpPost(url As String, query As String, alvara As String) As String
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = True
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = False
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000


        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url & 3274 & "/service1.php")
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentType = "text/xml"

        Dim postData As String = query
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        'dataStream.Close()

        Dim resposta As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        ' Console.WriteLine(CType(resposta, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
        dataStream = resposta.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim RespostaDoServidor As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        If RespostaDoServidor = "0" Then
            MsgBox("Erro de Comunicação")
            Return RespostaDoServidor

        End If
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        resposta.Close()

        Return RespostaDoServidor

    End Function

Function NomeDeAlunoPorID(IDAluno As Int16) As String
 ' return student Name using IDAluno

    Dim NomeDoAluno As String ' will be return value
    Dim resposta As String
    resposta = HttpPost("http://XXXXXXX.com/", "SELECT nome FROM aluno WHERE aluno_id='" & IDAluno & "' AND alvara='" & VariaveisGlobais.Alvara & "'", 3274)

    Dim Jresultado As JArray = JArray.Parse(resposta)
    Dim resultado As List(Of JToken) = Jresultado.Children().ToList() ' ficamos com uma lista dos campos

    ' loop por todos os campos de UM RECORD e adicionamos a uma HashTable
    For Each item As JObject In resultado
        Dim hash As Hashtable = New Hashtable

        For Each propriedade As JProperty In item.Properties()
            hash.Add(propriedade.Name, propriedade.Value.ToString)
        Next

        NomeDoAluno = hash.Item("nome")
        ' devolvemos o primero e único resultado possivel.
        Return NomeDoAluno
    Next

    ' se tivermos chegado aqui ocorreu um Erro
    NomeDoAluno = "Desconhecido"
    Return NomeDoAluno

End Function`
```

This one is for the student, there is another similar function for Instrutor (let's imagine is the course name from that example I was using.

I call this functions from main code to populate a datatable and the display a datagridview :

```
Private Sub PreparaTabelaUtilizacaoViatura()

    BtnEditar.Enabled = False
    btnGravar.Enabled = False
    ' formatar as grid
    dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.MultiSelect = False
    dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.MidnightBlue
    dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Lavender
    dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty
    dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray

    ' criamos uma tabela de dados em memória
    Dim UtilizacaoDeViaturas As New DataTable

    dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.DataSource = UtilizacaoDeViaturas


    ' resposta contem a resposta do servidor
    Dim resposta As String

    ' adicionamos as colunas à DataTable
    UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Columns.Add("Data")
    UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Columns.Add("Início")
    UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Columns.Add("Fim")
    UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Columns.Add("Tempo")
    UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Columns.Add("Aluno")
    UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Columns.Add("Instrutor")
    UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Columns.Add("Km")
    UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Columns.Add("Status")

    ' questionamos o servidor e receberemos um resposta
    resposta = UtilsHttp.HttpPost("http://XXXXXXXX.com/", "SELECT * FROM agenda_real_server WHERE viatura_id='" & ViaturaSelecionada.matricula & "' AND alvara='" & VariaveisGlobais.Alvara & "'", 3274)

    ' fazemos Parse do Json
    Dim Jresultado As JArray = JArray.Parse(resposta)
    Dim resultado As List(Of JToken) = Jresultado.Children().ToList() ' ficamos com uma lista dos campos

    ' loop por todos os campos de UM RECORD e adicionamos a uma HashTable
    For Each item As JObject In resultado

        Dim hash As Hashtable = New Hashtable
        For Each propriedade As JProperty In item.Properties()
            hash.Add(propriedade.Name, propriedade.Value.ToString)
        Next

        '// Temos um Record.Alguns campos são indices.
        '// Temos de os lêr na tabela original e substituir por Strings
        '// 

        ' o aluno
        Dim IDAluno As Int16
        Dim NomeAluno As String
        IDAluno = hash.Item("aluno_id")
        NomeAluno = UtilsHttp.NomeDeAlunoPorID(IDAluno)

        'Colocamos o nome do aluno no item da Hash respectivo, substituindo o indice
        hash.Item("aluno_id") = NomeAluno

        ' O instrutor
        Dim IDInstrutor As Int16
        Dim NomeInstrutor As String
        IDInstrutor = hash.Item("instrutor_id")
        NomeInstrutor = UtilsHttp.NomeDeInstrutorPorID(IDInstrutor)

        ' colocamos o nome do instrutor no item da Hash respectivo, substituindo assim o índice
        hash.Item("instrutor_id") = NomeInstrutor


        Dim UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow As DataRow = UtilizacaoDeViaturas.NewRow

        ' agora adicionamos uma row à dataTable
        UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow.Item("Data") = hash.Item("data")
        UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow.Item("Início") = hash.Item("hora_inicio")
        UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow.Item("Fim") = hash.Item("hora_fim")
        UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow.Item("Tempo") = hash.Item("duracao")
        UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow.Item("Aluno") = hash.Item("aluno_id")
        UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow.Item("Instrutor") = hash.Item("instrutor_id")
        UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow.Item("Km") = hash.Item("km_aula")
        UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow.Item("Status") = hash.Item("status_aula_id")

        UtilizacaoDeViaturas.Rows.Add(UtilizacaoDeViaturasRow)


        dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.Refresh()
    Next

    ' Temos a Tabela construida, Informamos qual o origem dos dados e mostramos a Grid
    ' dgvAnaliseDeUtilização.DataSource = UtilizacaoDeViaturas

End Sub
```

This is so slow, but so slow that can't be used, specially as I expect 200 users using the desktop application at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Disclaimer: this was extracted from the OP's question.</sub>

I was being sily by firing somany requests and parsing so many Json strings.

I constructed a SQL query using Inner Join and now I have all the data I want, including the names with only 1 single request and 1 Json parse.